# SharePoint learning kit reminder days

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, learning-kit, reminder

I am using **SharePoint Learning Kit** version *1.7* with SP2013.
I wish to set the user **remander email**, in the configurator file I case see this but I do not know the attribute meaning.
Where can I found a complete documentation of the *XML configuration file*?

```
<EmailSettings ReminderDays="1,7">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this post on SLK Codeplex project:
https://slk.codeplex.com/discussions/572734